# Recursively following callables dynamically when inspecting/disassembling code objects

Tags: python

I'm wanting to do some introspection on any function/method.  For all my examples I'm using Python 2.7, but using 3.3 is not a problem if it makes something easier.

Say I have the following code in a module called foobar.py:

```
def foo():
    bar()
```

I can see the code dynamically of foo running:

```
import inspect
import foobar
inspect.getsource(foobar.foo)
```

I can also get the disassembled bytecode from the code object of this function with:

```
import dis
dis.dis(foobar.foo)
```

Is there a way I can detect that the `foo` method calls another function (`bar` in this case) and then disassemble/inspect it dynamically?

I know that the code object itself has all sorts of attributes like the following:

```
>>> dir(foobar.foo.__code__)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'co_argcount', 'co_cellvars', 'co_code', 'co_consts', 'co_filename', 'co_firstlineno', 'co_flags', 'co_freevars', 'co_lnotab', 'co_name', 'co_names', 'co_nlocals', 'co_stacksize', 'co_varnames']
```

I've inspected most of them just looking around, but haven't quite found what I'm looking for.

The end goal is just a little experiment to see if I can recursively print out a would-be call stack without executing the code other than imports.  I know the theoretical call stack cannot account for runtime things like the state of particular variables, etc.  I would just like to print out the source of all nested functions given a certain call (even if the code would never execute a case based on the runtime state).

Also, I know that the `inspect` and `dis` modules can't help once I get into CPython code.  Ultimately it might be fun to print out a mapping of some kind that shows what CPython code it reaches when `inspect` and `dis` break down.  However, I'm not even sure if that is possible.

Comment: I sort of doubt that this is possible since `bar` cannot be resolved until runtime.  What if you had another function:  `def baz(): global bar; bar = 3` in the same module?  Then, if `qux` is called, `bar` isn't even a function when you call `foo` and you'll get an exception

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if this was possible anyway.  However, don't some static-analyzers like pylint do something like this to see if methods are resolved?  I'm just throwing out crazy ideas here.  I'm really just seeing if I could ultimately write a script that could print out all possible exceptions that could be raised (in pure Python) by a given function.

Comment: You could do this by running the programme, or you could attempt analysis of the programme to check for code which might rebind names, or you could write your own evaluator which assumes no clever tricks, and tries to statically resolve all references. None of these will be a super-easy afternoon hack.

Comment: @durden2.0 -- You might be able to walk through `foo.func_code.co_names` or something similar and try to find things in the assumed global namespace of `foo` with the same name that are callable -- rinse and repeat ;)

Comment: @Marcin What do you mean by running the program?  For my exceptions example I would have to execute the code and force it to raise every possible exception to see them right?  If so, I can't write a program to raise all the exceptions if I'm trying to write a program to *find* all the exceptions.  Maybe I'm confused ;)

Comment: @mgilson You bring up an interesting point. Is there a way to get the full path to a method/module/etc. if I just have the `co_names` list?  Maybe using `getattr` in someway?  Similarly, maybe a way to detect that name as a method call instead of global variable?

Comment: @durden2.0 Python is late bound. This means that the actual function to be called by a function call is determined at runtime, based on the state of the programme. Trying to determine the exact functions which will be called in the course of the programme is a variant of the halting problem (proof sketch: it is the exact same problem for any programme which might call a `loop_forever` function or which might recurse forever). As we know, that problem cannot *in general* be solved by static analysis of the programme in question, but can be answered by observing the behaviour of the programme.

Comment: @durden2.0 -- *shrugs* I don't know.  This is a little deeper introspection into the python interpreter than I've dug previously.

Comment: @mgilson I understand that determining exactly what function will be called on the state of the program is the halting problem.  However, what if I want to print all possible functions to be called?  The call tree is much larger in that case and not all *will* be reached, but I'd essentially like to see all possible paths through the code.

Comment: @mgilson I'm not sure if it's even possible.  I haven't done a lot of introspection, but I thought there might be a way with some magic hidden in the code objects.

Comment: Another idea for my exceptions script would be to just grep for `raise` but then I still have to reconcile all the callables and trace the Python code without using the real code objects.  Is there some other way to do this you guys can think of?  The solution doesn't have to be with lots of introspection.  I just thought it would be more correct..and fun. :)

Comment: You could try walking the Abstract Syntax Tree generated by python's compile() function and look for function declarations there.

Comment: @EricConner Could you provide a snippet or something explaining your idea?  I'm not at all an expert when it comes to the AST, etc.

Answer (score 2):

All compilers / interpreters build an Abstract Syntax Tree when parsing source.  This is a representation of the program based on its context free grammar which can then be recursively walked to generate code that can be executed by the machine.

Python provides access to its AST and you can walk this tree yourself and look for `ast.Call` objects inside of `ast.FunctionDef`.  A simple example is pasted below.  Note though that this will surely not at all capture all possible calls since calls can be embedded in other expressions, hidden by `eval` expressions, etc.  Here's a simple example:

```
import ast

source = """
def foo():
    bar()

def bar():
    baz()

def baz():
    print "hello!"
"""

def get_method_name_for_call(call_obj):
    for fieldname, value in ast.iter_fields(call_obj):
        if fieldname == "func":
            return value.id

def walk_method_calls(node, cur_func):
    if not node:
        return

    for cur_node in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
        if type(cur_node) == ast.Call:
            method_called = get_method_name_for_call(cur_node)
            print "Found a call to %s in body of %s." % (method_called, cur_func)
        walk_method_calls(cur_node, cur_func)


def walk_function_defs(node):
    if not node:
        return

    for cur_node in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
        if type(cur_node) == ast.FunctionDef:
            walk_method_calls(cur_node, cur_node.name)

# we pass <string> as a recognizable identifier since
# we have no filename
ast_root = compile(source, "<string>", "exec", ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)
walk_function_defs(ast_root)
```

And an execution example:

```
$ python abstract_tree.py 
Found a call to bar in body of foo.
Found a call to baz in body of bar.
```